# Mirror a 3d position vector3 based on a vector3 and rotation

Tags: unity, c#, 3d, mathematics

I have a point in 3d space and a coordinate with angle (a imaginary plane)

**Here's my input data :**

A ) a vector3 which defines a position in world space

B ) a vector3 which defines a mirror position

C ) a vector3 which defines rotation of mirror in Euler

**Now i want to mirror A based on B and C** (orange point)

[image: ExplainImage]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use normal vectors to define the plane, you can use [Vector3.Reflect](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Reflect.html):

[image]

```
public Vector3 GetMirroredPos(Vector3 mirrorPos, Vector3 mirrorNormal, Vector3 inputPos)
{
    var v1 = mirrorPos - inputPos;
    var v2 = Vector3.Reflect(v1, mirrorNormal);
    return mirrorPos - v2;
}
```

If you define the plane using Euler angles, you can convert it to a direction vector like this:

```
public Vector3 EulerToDir(Vector3 euler)
{
    return Quaternion.Euler(euler) * Vector3.forward;
}
```

Using a rotation to define a plane is not enough, you need to know its initial orientation. So it's better to use the normal vector to define it.

Comment: What do you mean from initial orientation? Mirror pos is a game object with Transform but points i want to mirror are just position vector3

Comment: @Cyclone The orientation of the mirror when not rotated is ambiguous, it is left or up depending on a temporary convention. Doing this will achieve your goal, but will cause trouble for later development. This is just a suggestion : )

Comment: I managed to make a perfect mirror with no future issues using quadtree and your answer helped me to shape the algorithm. accepted.